# Titanium Convert TiFile Object to TiFileSystemFile Object

Tags: iphone, file-upload, titanium, voice-recording

How to save the recorded audio file which is recorded using sound_record.js from Titanium KickenSink Source.

We have,

```
var file // global variable.

file = recording.stop(); // file will have recorded content which we will convert into media.sound in order to play.

var newDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'audioclips');
Ti.API.info("Created mydir: " + newDir.createDirectory());

var newFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(newDir.nativePath,'newfile.wav'); 
newFile.write(file.read());
```

But i am able to save the file which is recorded?

I am not getting how to save this recorded file, I dont knw where i am going wrong.

Please Help, 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you having the problem in saving the file or the problem is that your are unable to load the recorded file?

Comment: I am having problem in saving the recorded file. The content for the will be there in file object, but how do i create an actual .wav file using that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your are having problem with saving the file. In last line just change

```
newFile.write(file.read());
```

to

```
 newFile.write(file);
```

This should do the trick for you. 
Hope this helps.

**Edited:**

For saving the file try this code:

```
var newFile =Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'your_file.wav');

// Write the data.
newFile.write( file );
```

Comment: I tried your logic but its giving me this error
Result of expression 'newFile' [undefined] is not an object.

Comment: Muhammad I tried your code, It is ending up doing nothing, I am not able to save the audio file which is recorded.

Comment: Finally The Code worked. But i am not able to play that your_file.wav in the device.,Y is it so?

Comment: Everything is working great now. Thanks you so much for all the Help Muhammad.